# Is mold on new construction framing a concern?

Tags: mold, studs

I'm having a new construction home built. While touring the home, I noticed some black stuff on some of the wood (and gray stuff on other wood).

The builder tells me it's just from the wood sitting on the ground and will be cleaned before drywall. Does that seem reasonable? I'm less worried about the gray (which , but I don't want mold in my house.

Gray wood (might just be staining?):

[image]

Black wood (same board second picture is just closer):

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this is a concern for you, be sure to arrange to inspect this cleaning as "cleaned before drywall" will look a lot like "covered up by the drywall" after the drywall is hung.

Answer (score 4):

It's not uncommon for a few pieces of lumber to accumulate mold. While lumber is wrapped from the mill, it may spend time on wet surfaces or be splashed in heavy rain. Whether it's a concern is a matter of opinion. To me it isn't. Unless you're getting regular rain there that mold will dry out and die and never be heard from again.

Mold isn't the horror that many believe. Mold spores are *everywhere*. You're probably inhaling them now. They're only generally an issue in high concentrations or with severe health conditions. There's no such thing as a home without some (short of in a desert).

You could ask your builder to treat chemically, but that will probably introduce *more* moisture, and potentially more mold, which is not what I'd want.